# Simple method query

Tags: java, methods, if-statement, invoke

I have the following code which returns an error.

The line:

```
return first;
```

says:

> incompatible types, required: char[]

It seems like something simple, but I can't figure it out. I am trying to display the values from invoking `methodB`.

Also, you will notice I have commented an `if` statement as #4. Can someone further my understanding a bit.

Does this `if` statement update the value held by the variable `first` IF the value held in the current element in `alphas` comes before the current value of `first`?

Hope this makes sense and someone can help. Getting late and my brain isn't working any more. Java is going to make or break me!

```
package openuniversity;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        char [] alp = m.methodB();

        for (char b: alp)
        {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }

    public static char[] methodB()
    {

        char [] alphas = {'s','a','u','s','a','g','e'};
        char first = alphas[0];
        for (int i= 1; i < alphas.length; i++) //3
        {
            if (alphas[i] < first) //4
            {
            first = alphas[i];
            }
        }
        return first;
    }
}
```

Comment: `methodB` is declared to return `char[]` but you're trying to return a single `char`.

Comment: Thank you. 
Would you be able to tell me what I need to change? Removing the char [] from my method header isn't fixing the problem :/

Comment: I would seriously consider a beginner's guide to programming / java. You declare the method to return a specific type of thing, and you return that type of thing. If you try and return a different type of thing, it won't compile.

Comment: I am studying a module with the Open University (UK) which has left me absolutley stranded. The tutor is useless and confuses me more than helps me. I have a fantastic text that I am working through but I need to clear this up for an assessment. They are forcing me to run before I can walk and this is the result :(

Comment: "I have the following code which returns an error." No it doesn't, it gives a *compilation error.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package openuniversity;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        char alp = m.methodB();

        System.out.println(alp);
    }

    public static char methodB()
    {

        char [] alphas = {'s','a','u','s','a','g','e'};
        char first = alphas[0];
        for (int i= 1; i < alphas.length; i++) //3
        {
            if (alphas[i] < first) //4
            {
            first = alphas[i];
            }
        }
        return first;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function signature says you're returning a `char[]`:

```
public static char[] methodB()
```

But you actually return a `char`:

```
char first = alphas[0];
// ...
return first;
```

It's not entirely clear what you want to do, but you need to either change the signature to return a single char:

```
public static char methodB()
```

And change where it's used:

```
char alp = m.methodB();
```

Or make methodB actually return a `char[]`. The problem is I don't know what it's actually supposed to return. I'd suggest giving the function a better name. You may want to take a look at [Lists](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Thank you Brendan - this helps me kind of understand where I've gone wrong. As my comment above states, I am doing this as part of an online course which has left me stranded and I have no idea what the method is meant to do (no explanation was given) or what it is doing.

But I got the returned value, which is partly what I wanted. Many thanks for your help, must appreciated!